# installing numpy on xp python v 3.3

Tags: python, numpy

i have just installed python 3.3 on my xp machine.

i am now trying to install numpy. i downloaded the whl file: numpy-1.12.1rc1-cp27-none-win32.whl. it resides on my e:/python directory- this is my working directory

the python is itself installed in drive c:\python33.

this is what i am doing to install numpy:

1. i start my cmd prompt
2. i cd to drive e:\python
3. i type: c:\python33\Scripts\pip install numpy-1.12.1rc1-cp27-none-win32.whlnumpy-1.12.1rc1-cp27-none-win32.whl

after a couple of seconds, the command prompt appears and shows no errors and shows no confirmation messages either.

when i try to import numpy in python shell, it gives an error...basically cdnt find the numpy.

any tips on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: If you have pip installed, why not simply `pip install numpy`?

Comment: Also, you downloaded the cp27 wheel: that's for CPython 2.7, yet you want to use it with Python 3.3? Why?

Comment: @Evert u mean i type this in the shell or the command prompt?

Comment: @Evert i went to this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy ... and it does not have numpy for 3.3

Comment: Do you get any results from `pip3 install numpy --verbose --verbose --verbose`? Which is the most verbose you can get.

Comment: Why did you install Python 3.3, anyway? You should probably get something more recent. (If some other thing you need says it needs 3.3, it probably works with more recent versions, too.)

Comment: @Evert tried that.. nothing AT ALL!! .. maybe i shd uninstall python altogether and try fresh?

Comment: @user2357112 i was looking for an xp version..... can the latest versions run on xp??

Comment: Find the pip executable on your system, and open it in a text editor. Should be a small Python script file. Also, try `pip help` or `pip3 help`.

Comment: @mansooriqbal: Huh. I would advise you to upgrade your Windows, considering how crazy insecure XP is and how many things aren't going to run on XP as time goes on, but maybe you can't do that for some reason.

Comment: From python.org, it looks like Python 3.4 will work on XP, and there are Numpy wheels for 3.4, so you might be able to squeak by.  But in general you're going to be in a tough spot, because less and less stuff is going to work with XP.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do would to open you command line prompt and enter:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

or if you also want to install numpy for python v2:

```
pip install numpy
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i just tried that .... same thing....the pip3 executes but shows nothing was done. no error msgs no nothing!

Comment: Maybe try $ pip3 uninstall numpy and retype $ pip3 install numpy ? That might work